# Error en addEventListener ¿no es una funcion?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy teniendo un problema con el *JavaScript*, que aún no puedo solucionar. Les comento:

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que mediante una funcion **cree elementos** en el *html*. Funcionar, funciona pero a la hora de querer hacer un `addEventListener` me tira un error:

```
app.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function
```

¿Alguien podría explicarme a que se debe? Yo creo que debe ser un problema de ***scope***.

La idea es que puedo hacer eventos para darle más funcionalidad a la pagina, o sea esto me esta trabando para algunas cosas que quiero implementar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <h1 class="tittle">Lista de Compas</h1>
    <div class="inputStyle">
        <input type="text" id="textValue" class="inputTextStyle" maxlength="20">   <button id="btnEnviar" class="btnStyle1">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="divDimencion">
            <ul id="ulList" class="ulListStyle">
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="btnStyle">
 
    <button id="bntClear" class="btnStyle2">Clear</button>
</div>
  </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
let btnClear = document.getElementById("bntClear");
let bodyEntero = document.querySelector("body");
let ulList = document.getElementById("ulList");
let a = document.getElementsByClassName('labelStyle');

let newElements = () => {
        createLi = document.createElement("li");
        createCheck = document.createElement("input");
        createLabel = document.createElement("label");
        createLi.id = "propertyLi";
        createLi.classList ="LiStyle"
        createCheck.type = "checkbox";
        createCheck.id = "propertyCheck";
        createCheck.classList =" checkStyle";
        createLabel.id = "propertyLabel";
        createLabel.classList = "labelStyle";
        createLabel.textContent = textValue.value;
        createLi.appendChild(createCheck);
        createLi.appendChild(createLabel);
        ulList.appendChild(createLi);
}
let removeItems = () =>{
        let lis = ulList.childNodes.length;
        console.log(lis);
        for (let i = 1; i <= lis; i++ ){
            ulList.removeChild(ulList.firstChild);
        }
}
textValue.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    cleanInputText()
});
btnClear.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    cleanInputText();
    removeItems();
        alert("Lista de compras vacia");
});
btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (!textValue.value == " "){
        newElements();
}else{ 
    alert("Ingresar un producto");
} 
cleanInputText();
});
let cleanInputText = () =>{
    if (!textValue.value =='') {
        textValue.value=''
    };
}

a.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    console.log("asd");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema que veo es que creas los elementos html antes de acceder a estos.

Por lo tanto, debe mover su variable newElements() después de que el elemento html esté disponible,en tu caso :

```
let a = document.getElementsByClassName('labelStyle');
```

Yo dejaría el código así:

```
let newElements = () => {
        createLi = document.createElement("li");
        createCheck = document.createElement("input");
        createLabel = document.createElement("label");
        createLi.id = "propertyLi";
        createLi.classList ="LiStyle"
        createCheck.type = "checkbox";
        createCheck.id = "propertyCheck";
        createCheck.classList =" checkStyle";
        createLabel.id = "propertyLabel";
        createLabel.classList = "labelStyle";
        createLabel.textContent = textValue.value;
        createLi.appendChild(createCheck);
        createLi.appendChild(createLabel);
        ulList.appendChild(createLi);
}
let btnClear = document.getElementById("bntClear");
let bodyEntero = document.querySelector("body");
let ulList = document.getElementById("ulList");
let a = document.getElementsByClassName('labelStyle');

let removeItems = () =>{
        let lis = ulList.childNodes.length;
        console.log(lis);
        for (let i = 1; i <= lis; i++ ){
            ulList.removeChild(ulList.firstChild);
        }
}
textValue.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    cleanInputText()
});
btnClear.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    cleanInputText();
    removeItems();
        alert("Lista de compras vacia");
});
btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (!textValue.value == " "){
        newElements();
}else{ 
    alert("Ingresar un producto");
} 
cleanInputText();
});
let cleanInputText = () =>{
    if (!textValue.value =='') {
        textValue.value=''
    };
}

a.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    console.log("asd");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema de sincronizacion, el objeto a no se ha creado, pues lo creas con JS y luego intentas asignar algo cuanto el programa no lo ha generado en el DOM
consejo:
prueba poner un retrazo con `setTimeout` antes de la asignacion de a

```
 let a = document.getElementsByClassName('labelStyle');
```

igualmente no es lo ideal pero funcionará

lo otro es aserlo de manera adecuada, asi:

```js
let btnClear = document.getElementById("bntClear");
let bodyEntero = document.querySelector("body");
let ulList = document.getElementById("ulList");



let newElements = () => {
        createLi = document.createElement("li");
        createCheck = document.createElement("input");
        createLabel = document.createElement("label");
        createLi.id = "propertyLi";
        createLi.classList ="LiStyle"
        createCheck.type = "checkbox";
        createCheck.id = "propertyCheck";
        createCheck.classList =" checkStyle";
        createLabel.id = "propertyLabel";
        createLabel.textContent = textValue.value;
        createLi.appendChild(createCheck);
        createLi.appendChild(createLabel);
        ulList.appendChild(createLi);
        call_a(createLabel);
}
let removeItems = () =>{
        let lis = ulList.childNodes.length;
        console.log(lis);
        for (let i = 1; i <= lis; i++ ){
            ulList.removeChild(ulList.firstChild);
        }
}
textValue.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    cleanInputText()
});
btnClear.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    cleanInputText();
    removeItems();
        alert("Lista de compras vacia");
});
btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (!textValue.value == " "){
        newElements();
}else{ 
    alert("Ingresar un producto");
} 
cleanInputText();
});
let cleanInputText = () =>{
    if (!textValue.value =='') {
        textValue.value=''
    };
}

function call_a(a){
  a.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      console.log("asd");
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <h1 class="tittle">Lista de Compas</h1>
    <div class="inputStyle">
        <input type="text" id="textValue" class="inputTextStyle" maxlength="20">   <button id="btnEnviar" class="btnStyle1">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="divDimencion">
            <ul id="ulList" class="ulListStyle">
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="btnStyle">
 
    <button id="bntClear" class="btnStyle2">Clear</button>
</div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

cuando cliquees en el label mostrara los datos en consola